# Sending json to php server using jquery ajax - json error

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have problem with my form on my webpage. I am trying to use ajax and json to send the form values to php server, but I can't make properly json object.

**My JS code**

```
function sendJsonOpenPopout () {
    $('.submitBtn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var subject = $('.subject').val();
        var email = $('.email').val();
        var message = $('.message').val();

        var dataObject = {
            subject: subject,
            email: email,
            message: message
        }

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../../kontakt.php',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: dataObject,

        success: function(data){
             alert('Items added');
        },

        error: function(){
            console.log('You have fail');
        }

        //success: function(){
            //var createdDiv = '<div class="divToBeCentered"><p class="dataText">Wiadomość została wysłana pomyślnie.\brDziękuję za kontakt.</p></div>';
             //$('body').append(createdDiv);
         //}
    });
});
```

**My PHP code**

```
<?php 
    $str_json = file_get_contents('php://input'); //($_POST doesn't work here)
    $response = json_decode($str_json, true); // decoding received JSON to array
    $subject = $response[0];
    $from = $response[1];
    $message = $response[2];

    $to = "lubycha@gmail.com"; 
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"; 
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

I know there is similar question already asked, but the answers didn't help me.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: `url: '../../kontakt.php',` this is a suspicious line you giving directory path as a url it is wrong just use `http://yourdomain/kontakt.php`

Comment: I'm confused why $_POST would be empty. dataType is the expected response, not the type of data you are submitting. your type is set to POST.. data is an object which is sent to the server as a POST... There is nothing I see that tells me you are actively sending json data to a server as a string. So you are saying that if you `var_dump($_POST)` that it is empty?

Comment: It didn't help.
I thought the path is a problem, but I have checked it on several web pages and I am sure it should work just fine.

Comment: I have an error when I am trying to send the json to server, "You have fail" function. So you are saying I should change the "Post" type?

Comment: remove `contentType` since you aren't serializing your data to json and $_POST should work fine. Should also send something back from server in json format as you are requesting

Comment: PHP doesn't parse  JSON encoded request bodies. You will have to either send a form-urlencoded body, a multipart/form-data body, or it would be easier in your case to just change the request type to PUT and access your submitted data with $response instead of $_POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the json object and parse it on php side. Some variable might be named different, partly because some of it is pre-written code. Here are the steps I took.

**Folder Structure**

```
js/script.js
php/get_data.php
index.html
```

**Index.html**
a basic form.

```
<div id="feedback_panel" class="panel panel-default">
    <form id="feedbackform" name="feedbackform" method="post">
            <div class="form-group" id="email_wrapper" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="right">
                <label class="control-label" for="email">E-mail:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email@example.com" required>
                <span class="help-block"> </span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="subject_wrapper" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="right">
                <label class="control-label" for="subject">Subject:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
                <span class="help-block"> </span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="description_wrapper" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="right">
                <label class="control-label" for="message">message:</label>
                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="message." required></textarea>
                <span class="help-block"> </span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="feedback_submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**script.js**
upon submit, gather data and set it to an object and send to php via ajax.

```
$(function() {
    // process the form
    $('#feedbackform').submit(function(event) {

        // get the form data - obj that will POSTED to get_data.php
        var formData = {
            'email'       : $('#email').val(),
            'subject'     : $('#subject').val(),
            'message'     : $('#message').val()
        };

        // process the forum
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'php/get_data.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData, // our data object
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode      : true
        })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {
                // log data to the console so we can see
            if ( ! data.success) {
                console.log(data);
            } else {
                console.log(data);
            }

        });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

**get_data.php**
receives the data from script.js, do some validations, and then send and an e-mail.

```
<?php

$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data           = array();      // array to pass back data

// validate the variables ======================================================
    // if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array

$email;
$subject;
$message;


//check to see if the data exist, else write an error message,
function check_data(){
    $user_inputs = array();

    if (empty($_POST['email'])){
        $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';
        return false;
    }else{
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        array_push($user_inputs,$email);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['subject'])){
        $errors['subject'] = 'subject is required.';
        return false;
    }else{
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        array_push($user_inputs,$subject);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['message'])){
        $errors['message'] = 'message is required.';
        return false;
    }else{
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        array_push($user_inputs,$message);
    }

    return $user_inputs;
}

//getting array of data from check_data
$verify_data = check_data();


// return a response ===========================================================

// if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
if ( ! empty($errors)) {

    // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    // show a message of success and provide a true success variable
    $data['success'] = $verify_data;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';

    //if everything is good, sent an email.
    if($verify_data != false){
        send_email($verify_data);
    }
}

function send_email($info_data){
    // person who it going
    $to      = 'Email, Some <some_email@mailinator.com>';

    //subject of the  email
    $subject = $info_data[1];
    $result = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $info_data[2]);
    $result = nl2br($result);
    $result = wordwrap($result, 70, "\r\n");

    //body of the email.
    $message = "<html><body>";
    $message .= "<p style = 'width: 400px;'>" . $result . "</p>";
    $message .= "<br/>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";
    $headers = "From: Email, Some <some_email@mailinator.com>" . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: '. $info_data[0] . "\r\n" ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";


    //sent mail: check to see if it was sent.
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        $data["went"] = "went";
        $data['message'] = 'Success!';
    }else{
        $data["went"] = "didn't go";
        $data['message'] = 'Sorry!';
    }

    // echo the log
    echo json_encode($data);

}

?>
```

lot to cover, let me know if you any questions. I'll be happy to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was very usefull.

Comment: @GimmeSomeCode I'm glad it help you and you are welcome. Can you kindly mark this correct or vote up? or if you still need help or have a question about my code, let me know.

Comment: @GimmeSomeCode Thank you!

Comment: Np mate! Thank you again for helping me!