# How to do unsuccess to submit form jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem regarding my contact form page. I did callback after clicking the submit button. I tried not to fill `name` textbox but form still submits.

---

**My code:**

```js
function sendFeedback() {
  alert("Thank you for the feedback :)");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p class="font3">Name:</p>
  <input name="name" type="text" maxlength="50" size="30" required/>
  <br />

  <p class="font3">Email:</p>
  <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="" required/>
  <br />

  <p class="font3">Subject:</p>
  <input name="subject" type="text" required/>
  <br />

  <p class="font3">Message:</p>
  <textarea name="comment" row="80" cols="30" required></textarea>
  <br>
  <br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="sendFeedback()">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>
```

Comment: you can use event.preventDefault() to stop the default behaviour of the form. Have you tried that?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884011/sending-json-to-php-server-using-jquery-ajax-json-error/34889060#34889060 I'm doing validations and error handling here.

Comment: `alert` won't prevent submit. Suggest you study some form validation tutorials.

Comment: I thinks a possible duplicate of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted

Comment: Refer following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646471/stopping-form-submit-if-the-validation-fails

Answer (score 0):

You should change `<form>` to `<form onsubmit="test()"`,where `test()` would go something like this:

```
test(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  /* do some validations here */
  document.querySelector("form").submit();
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The form submitting and your alert triggering are two completely different things.  The `required` attributes you have on the inputs are working correctly. If you leave any of the required inputs blank, the form will not submit to the server, instead you'll trigger standard error messaging in whatever browser you're using (usually a red outline and a popover).

The bit of JavaScript you have (i.e. your alert) will trigger regardless of whether the form submits successfully or not since it's executed BEFORE the submit goes through. You need to either do something like `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` at the end of your function, but that will prevent the form from being submitted altogether.

As @dvenkatsagar said, your best option is to change your `onclick` to `onsubmit`.